# Bitmap to Jpeg using GPU (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, gpu, jpeg

I have a list of (Bitmap) Image, I need to convert to Jpeg and save it into memory stream. This is what I use:

```
  IEnumerable<Image> source (...)
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

  foreach (Image img in source)
  {
     img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
  }

  ms.Close();
```

There is a way to reduce CPU load and replacing the Save method with some GPU optimized library? Please provide the sample code.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need specialized JPEG compression library that will replace Image.Save. GPU acceleration is very hardware-specific, and I don't think that generic library for this ever exist. I know about [this](http://www.fastcompression.com/products/sdk/sdk.htm) proprietary product for CUDA, but it is for C/C++ (can be used from C# with pinvoke).

Before trying extreme GPU acceleration, I recommend to try alternative C# imaging libraries that could give better performance than standard .NET System.Drawing.Imaging API (you can start with libs listed [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/)).

Also you can check [C# TurboJpeg wrapper](https://github.com/qmfrederik/AS.TurboJpegWrapper). TurboJpeg is native lib that uses SIMD CPU instructions (MMX, SSE2, AVX2, NEON, AltiVec), and when SIMD instructions are supported it claims to be faster in 2x-6x than other jpeg codecs - possibly this will be enough for you (and you code will not be locked on concrete GPU hardware).

Answer (score 0):

The first library comes to mind is [CUDAfy.NET](https://cudafy.codeplex.com/)

You can run your methods with GPU instead of CPU, with only declaring an attribute:

```
using Cudafy;
using Cudafy.Host;
using Cudafy.Translator;

[Cudafy]
public IEnumerable<Image> SaveImages()
{
    IEnumerable<Image> source (...)
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    foreach (Image img in source)
    {
       img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

    ms.Close();

    return source;
}
```

This might be helpful for performance.

Comment: Are you sure that it really works for this code snippet?.. Most CPU load occurs inside Image.Save, which is internally calls OS API (Windows GDI) or native imaging library (say, on Linux). I may assume that Cudafy can translate only very simple IL code, and this has sense only for rather specific computations.

Comment: Cudafy makes it work on GPU: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202792/Using-Cudafy-for-GPGPU-Programming-in-NET

Comment: have you tested this code with Cudafy and it really gives performance improvement for Image.Save? This sounds to good to be true, as Image.Save internally calls native code which is definitely cannot be automatically translated into massively-parallel code for GPU.

Comment: When it comes to performance, it's not realistic to guarantee better results. It varies on your scenario and many different parameters much. This is merely a way of improving the execution. I'd love to hear the results for this specific case, however I cannot guarantee anything from the code block I got. Hence I wrote "This **might** be helpful"

Comment: Cudafy in this situation could not be helpful, even in theory. In article you mentioned, it is used for fast operations with large vectors (arrays), and GPU could be effective only with code that is specially written for massively-parallel computations. All this means that GPU could be used for hardware-accelerated jpeg compression, but this is possible only with specialized library that implements GPU-oriented compression algorithm.

Comment: I don't see any improvement, sorry